# Service can be both bound ans well as unbound

Tags: android, android-service

I have question for bind service.
I am having a class which binds with activity. If i kill the application then i am not able to get the notification.
I have added both `startService(myBindService)` as well as `bindService(connectionService, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` i m unbounding the service on destroy.
I want my service to do both the things running in background as well as binding with component.
Can I do that ?

Comment: you already did it by starting the service and binding to

Comment: but my service not running in background i smy issue

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `if i kill the application`? How are you "killing" the application?